# Fineness of product topology

Tags: general-topology

There is a theorem in **James.E.Munkres** that states that the uniform topology on $R^J$
is finer than product topology and coarser than the box topology when $J$ is finite. But there is also another statement in that state for finite products product topology and box topology are precisely the same.  Am I missing something?? Any help would be appriciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"Finer" and "coarser" are not strict relations.  That is, if a topology $T$ is finer than a topology $T'$, that means $T'\subseteq T$, not $T'\subsetneq T$.  So there is no problem if all the topologies you are talking about are equal.

(You may have misread something, though, since the statement that the uniform topology is finer than the product topology and coarser than the box topology is true for *any* set $J$, finite or infinite.  And in the infinite case, these topologies really are different.)

Comment: Yeah i know. But for infinite they are different. So we cant compare them. But then can we say uniform topology is coarser than product topology in finite product ??

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.